# Content disposition inline docx read only

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ms-word, content-disposition

I have following issue.

I am opening office DOCX file in IE browser via

```
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="file.docx"
```

everything is correct. File is correctly shown in IE frame, there is no problem here.

[image: File shown in IE frame]

Issue is, that this file does not look like read only mode. User can make changes in this file, and click save button (i am not sure save button does anything here). 
So user thinks, that when he make some changes and clicks on save button, that those changes will be stored on server. (or at least *save as* file will be asked)

**Question 1:** Is there any way to set word file opened via *content-disposition inline* as read only? Maybe some registry settings or IE settings or something?

**Question 2:** Where is this file opened locally? (I expect, that when word opens this file, it is stored somewhere on disk. Maybe i am mistaken)

**Question 3:** Can i hide at least toolbar when opening this word file via content-disposition inline?

Answer (score 0):

> Question 1: Is there any way to set word file opened via
>   content-disposition inline as read only? Maybe some registry settings
>   or IE settings or something?

Not found the way to set word file as read only using the content-disposition inline. But, if you want to make the word document read only, you could refer to the following steps:

1. Open the original word document using Office Word,
2. Click **Review** > **Restrict Editin**g,
3. Under **Editing restrictions**, check **Allow only this type of editing in the document**, and make sure the list says **No changes (Read only)**.
4. Click **Yes, Start Enforcing Protection**.
5. In the box that opens, type a password you’ll be able to remember, and then type the password again to confirm it.

   The password’s optional. But if you don’t add a password, anyone can click **Stop Protection** and edit the document.

   More detail information, please check [Make a document read only](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-a-document-read-only-5c25909c-46d9-4eb0-9d1f-d072a560e340).

> Question 2: Where is this file opened locally? (I expect, that when
>   word opens this file, it is stored somewhere on disk. Maybe i am
>   mistaken)

I have create a sample using the following code:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string localCopy = @"D:\Downloads\Document.docx";
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(localCopy);
        if (file.Exists == true)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

When I click the button, it will popup this window:

[image]

If we click the open option, the file won't be saved automatically, and it seems that we could edit the word document, but when we want to save it, it will create a new word document locally, it will not modify the original word document. So, don't worry about it.

If you want to save the file locally, click the Save or Save as option.

After that we could use the Office Word to view the word document.

> Question 3: Can i hide at least toolbar when opening this word file
>   via content-disposition inline?

Form your screenshot, it seems that you are also using Office word to view the word document, so we could not hide the toolbar. But if we make the word document read only, the toolbar like this (most of the function is unavailable):

[image]

If you just want to display the word document on the web page, I suggest you could refer to [this article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Word-document-on-web-page-in-ASP.Net.aspx), it will use the Microsoft Office Interop Library and read the document content and display them on the web page.